# Mean of tosses in equal square

Tags: probability, combinatorics, means

A fair die with sides numbered 1,1,2,2,3,3 is tossed until all 3 possible results are received. Let X be the number of times the result 1 was recieved. Calculate E(X). Answer by book: 11:6

I tried to assume the die was tossed k times and calculate P(X=x) using the law of total probability but I keep getting sums that I cannot solve..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1,2,3$ let $X_{i}$ denote the number of times that result
$i$ was achieved, so that $X=X_{1}$ and the $X_{i}$ have the same
distribution.

Let $Y$ denote the number of tosses needed to arrive in the situation
that all results are achieved.

Then:$$\mathbb{E}Y=\frac{3}{3}+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{1}=\frac{11}{2}\tag1$$(do you understand why?)

But also: $$Y=X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}$$so that: $$\mathbb{E}Y=\mathbb{E}X_{1}+\mathbb{E}X_{2}+\mathbb{E}X_{3}=3\mathbb{E}X\tag2$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find: $$\mathbb{E}X=\frac{11}{6}$$

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply
can you explain why E(Y) is 11:2? I don't understand the numbers in the sum...

Comment: We can write $Y=Y_{1}+Y_{2}+Y_{3}$ where $Y_{1}$ denotes the number
of throws needed to arrive in the sitation where one results has occurred
(so $Y_1=1=\mathbb EY_1$ ). $Y_2$ denotes the number
of further throws needed to arrive in the situation that two distinct
results are received ($Y_{2}$has geometric distribution with parameter
$\frac{2}{3}$ so that $\mathbb{E}Y_{2}=\frac{3}{2}$). Finally $Y_3$
denotes the number of further throws needed to arrive in the situation
that all results are received. $Y_3$ has geometric distribution
with parameter $\frac13$ so that $\mathbb{E}Y_3=3$.

Comment: This together
leads to $\mathbb{E}Y=\mathbb{E}Y_{1}+\mathbb{E}Y_{2}+\mathbb{E}Y_{3}=1+\frac{3}{2}+3=\frac{11}{2}$.